# Uncaught TypeError: "#edit_employment_type".val is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not sure how to fetch particular data in column from JSON with the help of keys. From ajax request i am getting data from the server but i want to store it in database as the columns in server.

This is my codes.

```
$(document).on('click', '#jobEdit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'/job/'+id+'/edit',
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#edit_employment_type').val(data.job.employment_type);
            $('#edit_job_type').val(data.job.job_type);
            $('#edit_history').val(data.job.history);
            $('#edit_post_title').val(data.job.post_title);
            $('#edit_state_id').val(data.job.state_id);
            $('#edit_city_id').val(data.job.city_id);
            $('#edit_start_date').val(data.job.start_date);
            $('#edit_end_date').val(data.job.end_date);
        },
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#jobUpdate', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var data = {
        'employment_type' : ('#edit_employment_type').val(),
        'job_type' : ('#edit_job_type').val(),
        'history' : ('#edit_history').val(),
        'post_title' : ('#edit_post_title').val(),
        'state_id' : ('#edit_state_id').val(),
        'city_id' : ('#edit_city_id').val(),
        'start_date' : ('#edit_start_date').val(),
        'end_date' : ('#edit_end_date').val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/job/'+id,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

I see this error.

[image: error]

Comment: How looks your corresponding html source?

Comment: When I click on jobEdit button It open like modal

Comment: If you want to get a helpful answer please provide a minimal runnable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example why and how.

Comment: `'employment_type' : ('#edit_employment_type').val()` - you missed the jquery `$`